# Parsing a date with

Tags: objective-c

I'm parsing a time using `NSDateFormatter`.  How do I move the `NSDate` object to the current day so that it will be 12:34pm with today's date?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:m a"];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"12:34 pm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get today's date/time from `NSDate`, then use `NSDateComponents` to break up both that and your `startDate`, copy the time components from one to the other, then translate back into an `NSDate`.

HTH